# Is $PROMPT_COMMAND a colon-separated list?

Tags: bash, shell, command-history

I want to enable my command history across all terminal tabs and windows to be recorded in `.bash_history` by setting `PROMPT_COMMAND` in `.profile`:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

However, when I check whether this environment variable is already set, I get:

```bash
echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"
```

Will exporting `PROMPT_COMMAND` like this overwrite my existing `$PROMPT_COMMAND` list or is it necessary to prefix the value of `PROMPT_COMMAND` with a `:` before exporting it?

Comment: It's a command. It has to look like a command. A colon will make it not look like a command.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams thanks for confirming that. How do I use PROMPT_COMMAND without overwritting the one that is already set or does it not overate since it is not a colon separated list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is $PROMPT_COMMAND a colon separated list?

That's easy enough to test:

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='true:true' bash 
bash: true:true: command not found
$ exit
```

So, the answer is "no".

But you could take it as a *semicolon* separated sequence of commands, as any other line of shell code:

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='echo x;echo y' bash 
x
y
$ exit
```

That's what the assignment in your question has: a number of commands, separated by semicolons, with the earlier value of `PROMPT_COMMAND` tacked on to the end.

Of course, another way to run multiple commands from `PROMPT_COMMAND`, would be to make a function and call it from there.

That said, the `printf` sequence in your `PROMPT_COMMAND` looks like something that might be better placed in the actual prompt instead, for two reasons. First, it doesn't end in a newline, so it may mess up Bash's idea of where the cursor is, just like other commands that output incomplete lines before exiting. Second, if you have the shell re-print the prompt, through tab-completion, `PS1` will be redisplayed, but `PROMPT_COMMAND` will not run again.

Comment: Thanks for showing how to test for it, it's very useful, but how do I use PROMPT_COMMAND without overwritting the value that is already set or does it not overwrite since it is not a colon separated list?

Comment: To touch on your last paragraph, that is the default PROMPT_COMMAND on my fedora system. I have not modified it in any way.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia, oh, sorry, that's the escape sequence for setting the window title. That makes more sense; it's not going to be visible on the prompt line. Anyway, the assignment you have should work in adding new commands to `PROMPT_COMMAND`, the semicolon works as a separator there.

Comment: Yes, I realise now that environment variables can be a colon separated list of values or a list of commands.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia, mmm, well. Colon-separated lists of paths are indeed common (`PATH`, `CDPATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, ... though the man page says the last one can also use semicolons as separators(!)). I don't think ones that take commands are that common, but then you have lots and lots of envvars that are really just single values (`LANG` and all the `LC_*`, `USER`, `EDITOR`...) or single paths (`HOME`, `MAIL`...). The wonderful thing is that they can be whatever the command that uses them wants them to be...

Answer (score 4):

As one of the top results on google when searching for `"PROMPT_COMMAND seperator"`, I feel like the answer deserves more effort than what has been given so far.

**NOTE:** In preparation for this post, I tested Bash versions 3.2, 4.4, 5.0, and 5.1 (via [docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/bash)) and reviewed the source code for the same versions (via [gnu.org](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/))

Let's begin ...

---

## Bash Manual(s)

### Bash <= v5.0

```
The value of the variable PROMPT_COMMAND is examined just before
Bash prints each primary prompt.  If PROMPT_COMMAND is set and
has a non-null value, then the value is executed just as if it
had been typed on the command line.
```

#### What does it mean?

It means bash does the general equivalent of:

```
eval "${PROMPT_COMMAND:-}"
```

So any chaining / sequencing of commands that would work for this `eval` is allowed.

### Bash >= v5.1

```
Bash examines the value of the array variable PROMPT_COMMAND
just before printing each primary prompt.

If any elements in  PROMPT_COMMAND are set and non-null, Bash
executes each value, in numeric order, just as if it had been
typed on the command line.
...
If this variable is set, and is an array, the value of each 
set element is interpreted as a command to execute
before printing the primary prompt ($PS1).

If this is set but not an array variable, its value is used 
as a command to execute instead.
```

#### What does it mean?

It means bash does the general equivalent of:

```
if [[ ${#PROMPT_COMMAND[@]} -gt 1 ]]; then
    for cmd in "${PROMPT_COMMAND[@]}"; do eval "${cmd:-}"; done
else
    eval "${PROMPT_COMMAND:-}"
fi
```

i.e each element of the array is `eval`'d independently

## What the community is doing

Making a search for [`"PROMPT_COMMAND"`](https://github.com/search?q=%22PROMPT_COMMAND%22&type=Code) on github shows that:

- By and large the community uses `;` as the separator
- Some occurrences use `$'\n'` as the separator

## What I've seen specifically

Some anecdotal notes:

- Mac OSX uses `;` (see `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` )
- [Bash-PreExec](https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec/blob/master/bash-preexec.sh) *appears* to use `$'\n'`
- [Bash-It](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/search?q=%22PROMPT_COMMAND%22) uses `;`

## Let's see them in action

First, lets get a fresh Bash v3.2 environment:

```bash
docker run -it --rm bash:3.2
bash-3.2$
```

### Semi-Colon-Delimited String

Testing with with a `;`-delimited string yields:

```bash
bash-3.2$ PROMPT_COMMAND='printf 1;printf 2;printf 3;printf ":\n"'
123:
bash-3.2$
```

### Line-Delimited String

Testing this with a `\n`-delimited string yields:

```bash
bash-3.2$ PROMPT_COMMAND=$'printf 1\nprintf 2\nprintf 3\nprintf ":\n"'
123:
bash-3.2$
```

#### Mix The Two

Can we mix the two separators? Yuupp! :

```bash
bash-3.2$ PROMPT_COMMAND=$'printf 1;printf 2\nprintf 3;printf ":\n"'
123:
bash-3.2$
```

### Howsabout Arrays?

Where we're going, we need Bash v5.1

```bash
docker run -it --rm bash:5.1
bash-5.1$
```

### Literal Array

Testing this with a literal array yields:

```bash
bash-5.1$ PROMPT_COMMAND=( "printf 1" "printf 2" "printf 3" "printf ':\n'" )
123:
bash-5.1$
```

###### USING ALL THREE !

What if you mix 'em all :

```bash
bash-5.1$ PROMPT_COMMAND=( "printf 1" $'printf 2\nprintf 3' 'printf 4;printf ":\n"' )
1234:
bash-5.1$
```

## Which one to use?

If `${PROMPT_COMMAND}` is an array, you should append/prepend your command to the array.

NOTE That you could append a command-group (i.e. a single `;` or `$'\n'`-delimited string of commands) as a single entry in the array if you like.

If `${PROMPT_COMMAND}` is not an array, then you should *probably* use `;` when adding your command(s), as it feels like a more official separator, but have the knowledge that the commands you add are allowed to be more complex scripts that can themselves include steps separated by `$'\n`'.

## Would I take a try at a munging function?

Sure !

```
##
# pc_munge munges PROMPT_COMMAND.
# Tries to accommodate when PROMPT_COMMAND is an array (supported in Bash v5.1+).
# If ${#PROMPT_COMMAND[@]} has 2+ elements, then we treat as an array, otherwise
# we defensively treat it as a string.
# By default, uses ';' as separator.
#
# NOTE: Does NOT check if command is already present
#
# Parms:
#  $1 command to add
#  $2 before | after (default: after)
#  $3 separator (default: ';')
#
pc_munge() {
    [[ -n "$1" ]] || return
    local fs="${3:-;}" # null | '' => default
    case "${2:-after}" in
        before)
            [[ ${#PROMPT_COMMAND[@]} -gt 1 ]] && PROMPT_COMMAND=( "$1" "${PROMPT_COMMAND[@]}" ) || PROMPT_COMMAND="${1}${PROMPT_COMMAND:+${fs}$PROMPT_COMMAND}"
            ;;
        *) # after
            [[ ${#PROMPT_COMMAND[@]} -gt 1 ]] && PROMPT_COMMAND+=( "$1" ) || PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND${fs}}${1}"
            ;;
    esac
}
```

[EDIT: Typo "PROMP_" => "PROMPT_"]

[EDIT: Typo "Som" => "Some"]

[EDIT: Typo "sing" => "single"]

Comment: In your "Which one to use?" section, you've got a typo: `${PROMP_COMMAND}` is missing the `T`

Answer (score 1):

bash's `$PROMPT_COMMAND` (or each element if it's an array with bash 5.1+ as already noted by @DavidFarrell) is interpreted as shell code, so you'd write its contents just like you'd write a shell script. In a shell script, commands can be separated by `;`, `newline`, `|`, `&`, `&&`,`||`, etc, each with its own meaning.

So you can have for instance:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='
  cmd1 && cmd2 &
  cmd3; cmd4
  for cmd in cmd5 cmd6; do
    "$cmd"
  done
  cmd7 << "EOF"
foo bar
EOF'
```

etc.

To append a command to an already set `$PROMPT_COMMAND` and make sure it's run independently of the previous ones, you've got the choice of `;` and *newline*, but `;` would not work if `$PROMPT_COMMAND` was initially empty or in the special case where it ends in a here document delimiter (like our `EOF` above), so doing:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND+='
  your extra command here'
```

(or with older versions:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=$PROMPT_COMMAND'
  your extra command here'
```

)

is preferable. Or:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='your extra command here
'$PROMPT_COMMAND
```

to prepend it so it's run first.

With bash 5.1+, you can also instead append an array element:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND+=(
  'your extra command here'
)
```

Or prepend:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=(
  'your extra command here'
  "${PROMPT_COMMAND[@]}"
)
```

That leaves one potential problem: if the `errexit` (`-e`) option is enabled, and any of the commands in those scripts fails, the processing stops there¹, so your extra command could end up not being run. That should probably be considered as a pathological case though. Using `errexit` in an interactive shell is probably a bad idea (it's already quite controversial when used in scripts).

For comparison, in `zsh`, instead of `$PROMPT_COMMAND`, you have hook functions that are called at various points, inspired by (and improved on) similarly named *special aliases* in `tcsh`. `precmd()` is the function you want to define so it be called before each prompt. In `zsh`, you can also instead set the `precmd_functions` special array with extra functions to be called (`errexit` also affects the processing there¹).

---

<sup>¹ same could happen with the `nounset` option or if a syntax error or any kind of fatal error is encountered during processing.</sup>